# Office365 - How to retrieve UPN using ImmutableId in powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-powershell

I have a office 365 user's immutableid. How using powershell i can retrieve corresponding user's UPN?

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, you can use the object identifier to query users in Azure AD.

```
$msolcred = get-credential
connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
get-msoluser -ObjectId "{guid:object_identifier}"
```

[image]

**UPDATE#1**: query user by ImmutableId

```
get-msoluser | Where-Object {$_.ImmutableId -eq "zYGi36Y8tkCwX4lYBb8bUA=="}
```

[image]

**UPDATE#1:**

Instead of using PowerShell get-msoluser module, another alternative option is using Microsoft Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=onPremisesImmutableId+eq+'zYGi36Y8tkCwX4lYBb8bUA=='
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have only immutableid and not objectid of o365 user.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, ya i ended up using the above cmdlet only. But what i thought was without processing all users in o365, is there a straight way to retrieve a user with immutableid. Because the above cmdlet involves scanning all users as you know..

Comment: @Praveen, for new feature request, you can submit a feedback on Azure Active Directory Feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory